Flutter: how Focus works for keyboard in iframe?
I met an interesting problem, I have a simple flutter build that use GestureDetector, MouseRegion, and Focus to listen for user input. GestureDetector listens to user clicking, and Focus listens to user keyboard input. When user click, number increases. When user types, number decreases.
Simply put, once user clicks the GestureDetector, it grabs focus for the Focus (focusNode.requestFocus()), and then increase a number by 1. Then, when user type in anything, number is decreased by 1.
The behavior is ok if app is directly opened (e.g. serving the build folder using python -m http.server 8080, then in browser directly go to http://localhost:8080).
However, if I put the app in an iframe (e.g. the iframe has src="http://localhost:8080"), keyboard actions are not triggered.
And here is my simple flutter code, you may try to reproduce:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int num = 0;
  FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); 
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTapDown: (details) {
                focusNode.requestFocus();
                setState(() {
                  num += 1;
                });
              },
              child: MouseRegion(
                cursor: WidgetStateMouseCursor.clickable,
                child: Focus(
                  focusNode: focusNode,
                  child: Text("hello world: $num"),
                  onKeyEvent: (FocusNode node, KeyEvent event) {
                    setState(() {
                      num -= 1;
                    });
                    return KeyEventResult.handled;
                  }
                ),
              )
            ),
            const TextField(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


<trivial...>
To build this app, simply run flutter build web.
Then, in build/web folder, one may run python -m http.server 8080
Here is the html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
      #showcase {
        width: 70%;
        height: 80vh;
        border-width: 0;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe id="showcase" src="http://localhost:8080"></iframe>
</body>

I tried comparing my implementation to a TextField. In the iframe setup, TextField works ok, when user clicks the textfield, it acquires focus, and is able to receive user's keyboard input.
Whenever TextField starts working, the GestureDetector works too.
I only tried on my macbook air: Channel stable, 3.24.1, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64
So there must be something clever had been done to TextField.... I wonder.... what is it?

Investigated further, document.activeElement shows that TextField is able to set iframe's focus, but Focus cannot.
